# Error connecting Python with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, installation, mysql-python

I received a python project and I'm having trouble running its requirements, particularly anything to do with MySQL. Whenever I run `pip install mysqlclient`, I get 13 warnings and this error in red.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-eBsQYy/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sxHiel-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-eBsQYy/mysqlclient/
```

When I run `pip install mysql-python` I get 14 warning with a similar error in red.

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-qW79lT/mysql-python/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-13maVa-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-qW79lT/mysql-python/
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you installed MYSQL locally ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yep I installed it with brew, what's the best way to check?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install “pymysql”. I got the warning as well trying to install MySQL for Python in Python 3. After doing some research, pymysql seems to be what needs to be installed moving forward. Pip install pymysql.

Comment: That didn't seem to work :( I installed `pymsql` but still get the error.